# Is it permissible to sit while praying if you started praying standing?

Tags: salat

Yesterday when I was praying, I was standing for so long that my legs started shaking uncontrollably, with this much pain I thought it would be impossible to have khushoo, therefore, after that salah, I thought about this and discovered that it might be sufficient to pray standing again, but when my legs start shaking I will sit down, in the same prayer, same rak'ah, without salam, and after I rest I will go back to standing, so:
Standing-Sitting-Standing.
Is this permissible?

Comment: You've asked a similar question already and I provided a link to a question with a general answer how much duplicates do you want to generate?

Comment: Nope, I asked a question about leaning, but this is one is about standing and sitting and then standing

Comment: And the linked answer answers it. See also [Standing in salahw ith chest a little forward incorrect?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50329/standing-in-salah-with-chest-a-little-forward-incorrect)